# My jQuery Won't Work on my Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, referenceerror

All of my HTML and CSS code works fine, and my script is properly linked (or so I assume), but I can't get the script to load or do any actions I've coded. Here's my HTML, CSS, and JS code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Highlights</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='testwebcss.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='testwebjs.js'></script>

</head>
        <body>
    <div id="title" class="highlighted">I'm highlighted!</div>
    <div id="text">Highlight me, too!</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
#title {
background-color: #C02942;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
height: 25px;
}

#text {
background-color: #0B486B;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Vivaldi, Cursive;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
height: 25px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.highlighted {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#text').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});

$('#text').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
});
```

So I don't understand why it's not working. As you can see, the script simply doubles the opacity when the mouse enters the perimeter of #text. So, why is nothing working. I got this from the console:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: try jQuery instead of $, if you have jQuery loaded

Comment: Try adding jQuery, as you didn't load it all !

Comment: I don't see where you have included reference to jQuery

Comment: +1 for trying a codecademy challenge in your browser. http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-v6phg/1/1?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1

Comment: @mr.musicman Thanks! I'm only 15 but I'm incredibly interested in Web Development, Java programming for Android Apps and Computer Applications, and C++ for a variety of applications.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the HTML head (before you include your script):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Highlights</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='testwebcss.css'/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='testwebjs.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="title" class="highlighted">I'm highlighted!</div>
        <div id="text">Highlight me, too!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try this, the webpage takes roughly 15 seconds to load, and then gives me this in the console:
`GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jguery/1.10.2/jguery.min.js  testweb.html:7`
Its an error.

Comment: You should open the HTML page by `http://` via a local web server, not by `file://` from local disk file system. jQuery isn't available in your local disk file system. Otherwise, you have to manually download it and drop it next to your JS file and reference it like `src="jquery.min.js"`. But still, it's strongly recommended to install a true web server on your machine.

Comment: You've mixed up your 'g's and 'q's; the file is `jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` not `jguery/1.10.2/jguery.min.js`.

Comment: @user2869332 - as noted by BalusC, install a webserver, it takes two minutes and you really do need it, as you'll soon be experiencing weird problems when running on the local filesystem like that.

Comment: In installed and setup the XAMPP local webserver with Apache and MySQL. I installed a folder with the necessary files (the HTML, CSS, and JS source files). I ran the site with: http://localhost/testsite/webtest.html

I still get the same thing from just running the HTML file itself.